# Change a CardView's row in a RecyclerView every x sec

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, cardview

Good morning,
I am looking for an answer to my problem and I have not found.
I want to change a single line of a CardView contained in a RecyclerView every x seconds. Just like Google+ where messages are changed every x seconds. 
See image

[google_plus_1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UiPY1.jpg) 
[google_plus_2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M7Om.jpg)

Grazie!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to do the follow steps.

1. fetch the data and set it you recyclerview.
2. wait for x second and again fetch the data. then set it to you adapter and call

`yourAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

3. your list will be refreshed.

you know na how to set recyclerView.

Comment: I added into the fragment in which I create the adapter:

It works, thank you! Good day!

Comment: upvote my answer so i may helpful to others also @B.Anto

Comment: I can't do it because my reputation is less than 15